# Mutable variable becoming unreturnable when assigned to a variable

Tags: rust

When I try to do `selector = &mut (Value of potential selector)` it works. But when I try to assign to a temporary variable to then check if it is `Some`, it cannot be returned.

I tried to add a lifetime but I only got syntax errors.

```rust
use std::option::Option;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Node<Record> {
    pub character: char,
    pub children: Vec<Node<Record>>,
    pub record: Option<Record>
}

struct Matcher<Record> {
    root_node: Node<Record>
}

impl<Record> Matcher<Record> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            root_node: Node {
                character: 'f',
                children: Vec::new(),
                record: None
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn test(&mut self) {
        let left = Node { character: 'l', children: Vec::new(), record: None };
        let right = Node { character: 'r', children: Vec::new(), record: None };

        self.root_node.children.push(left);
        self.root_node.children.push(right);
    }

    pub fn find_mutably<'a>(&mut self, path: &[char]) -> Option<&mut Node<Record>> {
        let mut selector: &mut Node<Record> = &mut self.root_node;

        for path_segment_index in 0..path.len() {
            let path_segment = path[path_segment_index];
            let potential_selector = selector
                .children
                .iter_mut()
                .find(|child| child.character == path_segment);

            // if let Some(mut new_selector) = potential_selector {
                selector = &mut potential_selector.unwrap();
            // } else {
            //     return None;
            // }
        }

        Some(selector) // Error happens here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_selector` is a `&mut Node<Record>`, which matches `selector`. You can assign it directly:

```
pub fn find_mutably<'a>(&mut self, path: &[char]) -> Option<&mut Node<Record>> {
    let mut selector: &mut Node<Record> = &mut self.root_node;

    for path_segment_index in 0..path.len() {
        let path_segment = path[path_segment_index];
        let potential_selector = selector
            .children
            .iter_mut()
            .find(|child| child.character == path_segment);

        if let Some(new_selector) = potential_selector {
            selector = new_selector;
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    }

    Some(selector)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c19d9dc26cd2cbded71b7de59bfa923c)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bad compiler error message — if you get rid of the `&mut` in front of `potential_selector.unwrap()`, it compiles.